# How to calculate no. of palindroms in a large number interval?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, palindrome

I want to calculate how many numbers are palindrome in large interval data say `10^15`

My simple code (python) snippet is:

```
def count_palindromes(start, end):
    count = 0
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]:
            count += 1

    return count

start = 1000 #some initial number
end = 10000000000000 #some other large number

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print count_palindromes(start, end)
```

Its a simple program which checks each number one by one. Its vary time consuming and takes a lot of computer resources.

Is there any other method/technique by which we can count Palindrome numbers? Any Algorithm to use for this?

I want to minimize time taken in producing the output.

Comment: This is a currently active problem in Code Jam. The qualification round ends in a little under 12 hours.

Comment: @Ben really? I flagged it

Comment: @Ben That's a pity. It's a problem with a nice quick solution.

Comment: @DanielFischer Make sure to post that solution in about 12 hours please, I'd be interested.

Comment: @G.Bach I'm going to be asleep then. Unless somebody else has posted the quick solution (or maybe an even better one?) before that, I'll post tomorrow (should be before noon UTC) and ping you.

Comment: @G.Bach Posted it. If you like it, tell your friends. If not, tell me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you want to count the numbers having some given property between two limits, it is often useful to solve the somewhat simpler problem

> How many numbers with the given property are there between `0` and `n`?

Keeping one limit fixed can make the problem significantly simpler to tackle. When the simpler problem is solved, you can get the solution to the original problem with a simple subtraction:

```
countBetween(a,b) = countTo(b) - countTo(a)
```

or `countTo(b ± 1) - countTo(a ± 1)`, depending on whether the limit is included in `countTo` and which limits shall be included in `countBetween`.

If negative limits can occur (not for palindromes, I presume), `countTo(n)` should be `<= 0` for negative `n` (one can regard the function as an integral with respect to the counting measure).

So let us determine

```
palindromes_below(n) = #{ k : 0 <= k < n, k is a palindrome }
```

We get more uniform formulae for the first part if we pretend that 0 is not a palindrome, so for the first part, we do that.

**Part 1:** How many palindromes with a given number `d` of digits are there?

The first digit cannot be `0`, otherwise it's unrestricted, hence there are 9 possible choices (`b-1` for palindromes in an arbitrary base `b`).

The last digit is equal to the first by the fact that it shall be a palindrome.

The second digit - if `d >= 3` - can be chosen arbitrarily and independently from the first. That also determines the penultimate digit.

If `d >= 5`, one can also freely choose the third digit, and so on.

A moment's thought shows that for `d = 2*k + 1` or `d = 2*k + 2`, there are `k` digits that can be chosen without restriction, and one digit (the first) that is subject to the restriction that it be non-zero. So there are

```
9 * 10**k
```

`d`-digit palindromes then (`(b-1) * b**k` for base `b`).

That's a nice and simple formula. From that, using the formula for a geometric sum, we can easily obtain the number of palindromes smaller than 10<sup>n</sup> (that is, with at most `n` digits):

- if `n` is even, the number is

  ```
     n/2-1                n/2-1
  2 *  ∑ 9*10**k =  18 *    ∑ 10**k = 18 * (10**(n/2) - 1) / (10 - 1) = 2 * (10**(n/2) - 1)
      k=0                  k=0
  ```
- if `n` is odd, the number is

  2 * (10**((n-1)/2) - 1) + 9 * 10**((n-1)/2) = 11 * (10**((n-1)/2) - 2

(for general base `b`, the numbers are `2 * (b**(n/2) - 1)` resp. `(b+1) * b**((n-1)/2) - 2`).

That's not quite as uniform anymore, but still simple enough:

```
def palindromes_up_to_n_digits(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 2*10**(n//2) - 2
    else:
        return 11*10**(n//2) - 2
```

(remember, we don't count 0 yet).

Now for the remaining part. Given `n > 0` with `k` digits, the palindromes `< n` are either

- palindromes with fewer than `k` digits, there are `palindromes_up_to_n_digits(k-1)` of them, or
- palindromes with exactly `k` digits that are smaller than `n`.

So it remains to count the latter.

**Part 2:**

Let`m = (k-1)//2` and

```
d[1] d[2] ... d[m] d[m+1] ... d[k]
```

the decimal representation of `n` (the whole thing works with the same principle for other bases, but I don't explicitly mention that in the following), so

```
    k
n = ∑ d[j]*10**(k-j)
   j=1
```

For each `1 <= c[1] < d[1]`, we can choose the `m` digits `c[2], ..., c[m+1]` freely to obtain a palindrome

```
p = c[1] c[2] ... c[m+1] {c[m+1]} c[m] ... c[2] c[1]
```

(the digit `c[m+1]` appears once for odd `k` and twice for even `k`). Now,

```
c[1]*(10**(k-1) + 1) <= p < (c[1] + 1)*10**(k-1) <= d[1]*10**(k-1) <= n,
```

so all these `10**m` palindromes (for a given choice of `c[1]`!) are smaller than `n`.

Thus there are `(d[1] - 1) * 10**m` `k`-digit palindromes whose first digit is smaller than the first digit of `n`.

Now let us consider the `k`-digit palindromes with first digit `d[1]` that are smaller than `n`.

If `k == 2`, there is one if `d[1] < d[2]` and none otherwise. If `k >= 3`, for each `0 <= c[2] < d[2]`, we can freely choose the `m-1` digits `c[3] ... c[m+1]` to obtain a palindrome

```
p = d[1] c[2] c[3] ... c[m] c[m+1] {c[m+1]} c[m] ... c[3] c[2] d[1]
```

We see `p < n`:

```
d[1]*(10**(k-1) + 1) + c[2]*(10**(k-2) + 10)
         <= p < d[1]*(10**(k-1) + 1) + (c[2] + 1)*(10**(k-2) + 10)
         <= d[1]*(10**(k-1) + 1) + d[2]*(10**(k-2) + 10) <= n
```

(assuming `k > 3`, for `k == 3` replace `10**(k-2) + 10` with 10).

So that makes `d[2]*10**(m-1)` `k`-digit palindromes with first digit `d[1]` and second digit smaller than `d[2]`.

Continuing, for `1 <= r <= m`, there are

```
d[m+1]*10**(m-r)
```

`k`-digit palindromes whose first `r` digits are `d[1] ... d[r]` and whose `r+1`<sup>st</sup> digit is smaller than `d[r+1]`.

Summing up, there are

```
(d[1]-1])*10**m + d[2]*10**(m-1) + ... + d[m]*10 + d[m+1]
```

`k`-digit palindromes that have one of the first `m+1` digits smaller than the corresponding digit of `n` and all preceding digits equal to the corresponding digit of `n`. Obviously, these are all smaller than `n`.

There is one `k`-digit palindrome `p` whose first `m+1` digits are `d[1] .. d[m+1]`, we must count that too if `p < n`.

So, wrapping up, and now incorporating 0 too, we get

```
def palindromes_below(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    if n < 10:
        return n   # 0, 1, ..., n-1

    # General case
    dec = str(n)
    digits = len(dec)
    count = palindromes_up_to_n_digits(digits-1) + 1   # + 1 for 0
    half_length = (digits-1) // 2
    front_part = dec[0:half_length + 1]
    count += int(front_part) - 10**half_length
    i, j = half_length, half_length+1
    if digits % 2 == 1:
        i -= 1
    while i >= 0 and dec[i] == dec[j]:
        i -= 1
        j += 1
    if i >= 0 and dec[i] < dec[j]:
        count += 1
    return count
```

Since the limits are both to be included in the count for the given problem (unless the OP misunderstood), we then have

```
def count_palindromes(start, end):
    return palindromes_below(end+1) - palindromes_below(start)
```

for a fast solution:

```
>>> bench(10**100,10**101-1)
900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 palindromes between
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
and
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
in 0.000186920166016 seconds
```

Comment: That's a nice solution to the OP, but FWIW it's almost irrelevant to the codejam question, which asks for palindromes which are squares of palindromes. Generating long palindromes and rejecting them if their square root is not palindromic is obviously inferior to generating short palindromes and rejecting them if their square is not palindromic. However, the real key to solving the cj question is noting under what circumstances the square of a palindrome could in turn be a palindrome which results in a much more limited range of possibilities (thousands at worst).

Comment: Ah, yes, that's an entirely different question. I wonder why this question was said to be a Code Jam problem, then.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's a problem for Google Codejam (which I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to get outside help on) but alas, I'll throw in my 2 cents.

The idea I came up with (but failed to implement) for the large problem was to precompile (generated at runtime, not hardcoded into the source) a list of all palindromic numbers less than `10^15` (there's not very many, it takes like ~60 seconds) then find out how many of those numbers lie between the bounds of each input.

EDIT: This won't work on the `10^100` problem, like you said, that would be a mathematical solution (although there is a pattern if you look, so you'd just need an algorithm to generate all numbers with that pattern)

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is for something like Project Euler... my rough idea would be to generate all numbers up to half the length of your limit (like, if you're going to 99999, go up to 99). Then reverse them, append them to the unreversed one, and potentially add a digit in the middle (for the numbers with odd lengths). You'll might have to do some filtering for duplicates, or weird ones (like if you had a zero at the beginning of the number or sommat) but that should be a lot faster than what you were doing.

Comment: I doubt this would be fast enough but maybe you can try it out. Looks like more of a mathematical problem to me

Comment: True... you could just do this kind of approach but just work with the number of numbers, rather than the actual numbers themselves.

Comment: There is a pattern, anyway this needs to be closed since its against the rules